# LEFT JOIN Causes Duplicate Result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've put together a simplified version of the problem here.

## Scenario

- My application has Users, Files, and Folders.
- A user can create private files that only he can see and shared files that all users can see.
- A user can create private folders that he can organize his private and shared files into. Folder assignment is optional however. If the user doesn't assign a folder, the file is shown in an "uncategorized" bin.

## Schema

```
-- -------------------------------------
-- User
-- -------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE [User] (
  [Id] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO [User]
  VALUES ('user_1');
INSERT INTO [User]
  VALUES ('user_2');

-- -------------------------------------
-- Folder
-- -------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE [Folder] (
    [Id] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

-- Each user has a private folder
INSERT INTO [Folder]
  VALUES ('user1_folder', 'user_1');
INSERT INTO [Folder]
  VALUES ('user2_folder', 'user_2');

-- -------------------------------------
-- File
-- -------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE [File] (
  [Id] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  [UserId] VARCHAR(50) NULL
);

-- Private files
INSERT INTO [File]
  VALUES ('user1_file1', 'user_1');
INSERT INTO [File]
  VALUES ('user1_file2', 'user_1');

INSERT INTO [File]
  VALUES ('user2_file1', 'user_2');
INSERT INTO [File]
  VALUES ('user2_file2', 'user_2');

-- Shared files
INSERT INTO [File]
  VALUES ('shared_file1', NULL);
INSERT INTO [File]
  VALUES ('shared_file2', NULL);
INSERT INTO [File]
  VALUES ('shared_file3', NULL);
-- UPDATE: new case
INSERT INTO [File]
  VALUES ('shared_file4', NULL);

-- -------------------------------------
-- FolderFile Association
-- -------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE [FolderFile] (
    [FolderId] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [FileId] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

-- User 1 puts some files in his private folders
INSERT INTO [FolderFile]
  VALUES ('user1_folder', 'user1_file');
INSERT INTO [FolderFile]
  VALUES ('user1_folder', 'shared_file1');
INSERT INTO [FolderFile]
  VALUES ('user1_folder', 'shared_file2');

-- User 2 puts some files in his private folders
INSERT INTO [FolderFile]
  VALUES ('user2_folder', 'user2_file');
INSERT INTO [FolderFile]
  VALUES ('user2_folder', 'shared_file1');
-- UPDATE: new case
INSERT INTO [FolderFile]
  VALUES ('user2_folder', 'shared_file4');
```

## Desired Result

I want to see all private and shared files for the given `@UserId` (`user_1` in this case), along with the associated private folder for that user (if it has one). **Note that a folder is optional for a user's file**.

## Attempted Query #1

```
DECLARE @UserId VARCHAR(50) = 'user_1'

SELECT
  F.[Id] AS [FileId],
  F.[UserId] AS [FileUserId],
  FO.[Id] AS [FolderId]
FROM
  [File] AS F
LEFT JOIN
  [FolderFile] FOF ON FOF.[FileId] = F.[Id]
LEFT JOIN
  [Folder] FO ON FO.[Id] = FOF.[FolderId]
WHERE
  F.[UserId] IS NULL
  OR F.[UserId] = @UserId
```

## Result #1

```
FileId          FileUserId    FolderId
=========================================
user1_file1     user_1        NULL
user1_file2     user_1        NULL
shared_file1    NULL          user1_folder
shared_file1    NULL          user2_folder   <== bad result
shared_file2    NULL          user1_folder
shared_file3    NULL          NULL
shared_file4    NULL          user2_folder   <== bad result
```

## Attempted Query #2

Adding another condition to the `Folder` `JOIN` `ON`.

```
DECLARE @UserId VARCHAR(50) = 'user_1'

SELECT
  F.[Id] AS [FileId],
  F.[UserId] AS [FileUserId],
  FO.[Id] AS [FolderId]
FROM
  [File] AS F
LEFT JOIN
  [FolderFile] FOF ON FOF.[FileId] = F.[Id]
LEFT JOIN
  [Folder] FO ON FO.[Id] = FOF.[FolderId] AND FO.[UserId] = @UserId -- Add another condition here on UserId
WHERE
  F.[UserId] IS NULL
  OR F.[UserId] = @UserId
```

## Result #2

```
FileId          FileUserId    FolderId
=========================================
user1_file1     user_1        NULL
user1_file2     user_1        NULL
shared_file1    NULL          user1_folder
shared_file1    NULL          NULL           <== bad result
shared_file2    NULL          user1_folder
shared_file3    NULL          NULL
shared_file4    NULL          NULL
```

## Analysis

As you can see above, the association for `user_2`'s folder is causing an extra row to be returned for `user_1`. I do not want this row to be included.

If the `FolderFile` table had a `UserId` on it I think I could limit it there with a conditional, but it doesn't. The `UserId` is implied through the associated `Folder`. The `LEFT JOIN`s on the association are causing it to propagate null and pass the conditions below it.

I'm running out of ideas, though it's probably something obvious :)

## UPDATE #1

I added a new case with `shared_file4`, which is in a folder for `user_2`, but not `user_1`. It should be included in the results for both users.

```
INSERT INTO [File]
  VALUES ('shared_file4', NULL);

INSERT INTO [FolderFile]
  VALUES ('user2_folder', 'shared_file4');
```

Comment: If your only way to represent a _shared_ file is to assign NULL as the file owner, and there is no representation for a _shared_ or _private_ folder, then it will be difficult to tell that a shared file is private in some folders. Using a `bit` to indicate the shared/private status of each file and folder would probably work out better, and it would allow you to track ownership independently of sharing by assigning a `UserId` to every file and folder.

Comment: Not talk about table design, could you explain why bad result in `result #1` while you have `INSERT INTO [FolderFile]
  VALUES ('user2_folder', 'shared_file1');` ?

Comment: @PhamX.Bach because folder assignment is private. The queries should only be returning results for `user_1`.

Comment: @HABO Ok, Let's pretend there is a `[Shared] BIT NOT NULL` on the `File` table (true for all files that have a `NULL` `UserId`). How can I adjust the queries with that new information to solve the problem?

Comment: You need to define what "shared" really means, e.g. a file _within a path_ is always private unless: (1) the file's _shared_ bit is set **and** (b) every folder on the path has its _shared_ bit set. Then code accordingly. I'd probably use a Common Table Expression (CTE) recursively to handle nested folders. Thus "X:\BillyBob\Secret\Public.txt" would likely be private while the same file accessed as "A:\Thurston\SharedStuff\Favorites\Public.txt" would likely be shared.

Comment: @HABO File paths are not in question here. This is just a simplified version of the real problem. The real solution isn't even called files :)

Comment: Rereading the question: All files with a NULL `UserId` are shared, regardless of any (or no) assignment to folders. You want to get all of the shared files and, for a given `UserId`, the user's folders (if any) which contain the shared files. Correct?

Comment: @HABO that is correct.

Comment: Though many of the answers given were able to return the result set that I needed, they didn't offer very good query plans. I ultimately decided the best way to achieve my desired result-set with optimal performance was to denormalize the `FolderFile` table and add a `UserId` column. With this column now available, I can stick with standard joins similar to my original query attempts, filtering the user at the `FolderFile` `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though many of the answers given were able to return the result set that I needed, they didn't offer very good query plans. I ultimately decided the best way to achieve my desired result-set with optimal performance was to denormalize the `FolderFile` table and add a `UserId` column. With this column now available, I can stick with standard joins similar to my original query attempts, filtering the user at the `FolderFile` `LEFT JOIN`.

```
CREATE TABLE [FolderFile] (
    [FolderId] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [FileId] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

---

```
SELECT
  F.[Id] AS [FileId],
  F.[UserId] AS [FileUserId],
  FO.[Id] AS [FolderId]
FROM
  [File] AS F
LEFT JOIN
  [FolderFile] FOF ON FOF.[FileId] = F.[Id] AND FOF.[UserId] = @UserId
LEFT JOIN
  [Folder] FO ON FO.[Id] = FOF.[FolderId]
WHERE
  F.[UserId] IS NULL
  OR F.[UserId] = @UserId
```

Answer (score 2):

There's already some good answers about LEFT JOIN.  I decided to play around with CTE's and see if I could make a very expressive answer instead.  Enjoy:

```
DECLARE @UserId VARCHAR(50) = 'user_1'

;WITH
PrivateFile (FileId) AS
(
  SELECT Id FROM [File]
  WHERE UserId = @UserId
),
SharedFile (FileId) AS
(
  SELECT Id FROM [File]
  WHERE UserId is null
),
AnyFile ([FileId]) AS
(
  SELECT FileId FROM PrivateFile
  UNION
  SELECT FileId FROM SharedFile
),
PrivateFolder (FolderId) AS
(
  SELECT Id FROM [Folder]
  WHERE UserId = @UserId
),
AssociatedFolder ([FileId], [FolderId]) AS
(
  SELECT ff.FileId, ff.FolderId
  FROM [FolderFile] ff
    JOIN PrivateFolder pf ON ff.FolderId = pf.FolderId
)
SELECT f.[FileId], @UserId as UserId, fo.[FolderId]
FROM AnyFile as f
  LEFT JOIN AssociatedFolder as fo ON f.[FileId] = fo.[FileId]
```

Answer (score 2):

This provides the desired answers for the given data.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Users as Table ( UserId VarChar(50) not NULL );
insert into @Users ( UserId ) values
  ( 'user_1' ), ( 'user_2' );

declare @Folders as Table ( FolderId VarChar(50) not NULL, UserId VarChar(50) not NULL );
insert into @Folders ( FolderId, UserId ) values
  ( 'user1_folder', 'user_1' ), ( 'user2_folder', 'user_2' );

declare @Files as Table ( FileId VarChar(50) not NULL, UserId VarChar(50) NULL );
insert into @Files ( FileId, UserId ) values
  -- Private files.
  ( 'user1_file1', 'user_1' ), ( 'user1_file2', 'user_1' ),
  ( 'user2_file1', 'user_2' ), ( 'user2_file2', 'user_2' ),
  -- Shared files.
  ( 'shared_file1', NULL ), ( 'shared_file2', NULL ), ( 'shared_file3', NULL ), ( 'shared_file4', NULL );

declare @FileFolders as Table ( FolderId VarChar(50) not NULL, FileId VarChar(50) not NULL );
insert into @FileFolders ( FolderId, FileId ) values
  -- User 1 puts some files in his private folders.
  ( 'user1_folder', 'user1_file' ), ( 'user1_folder', 'shared_file1' ), ( 'user1_folder', 'shared_file2' ),
  -- User 2 puts some files in his private folders.
  ( 'user2_folder', 'user2_file' ), ( 'user2_folder', 'shared_file1' ), ( 'user2_folder', 'shared_file4' );

select * from @Users;
select * from @Files;
select * from @Folders;
select * from @FileFolders;

-- Query the data.
declare @UserId as VarChar(50) = 'user_1';

with
  -- Any file with a   UserId   of   NULL is shared.
  --   If it is in the given user's folders then pick up the folder.
  SharedFiles as (
    select Fi.FileId, Max( Fi.UserId ) as UserId, Max( Fo.FolderId ) as FolderId
      from @Files as Fi left outer join
        @FileFolders as FF on FF.FileId = Fi.FileId left outer join
        @Folders as Fo on Fo.FolderId = FF.FolderId and ( Fo.UserId = @UserId or FF.FileId is NULL )
      where Fi.UserId is NULL
      group by Fi.FileId ),
  -- Any file with a non-NULL   UserId   is private.
  --   Find all of the given user's files.
  PrivateFiles as (
    select Fi.FileId, Fi.UserId, Fo.FolderId
      from @Files as Fi left outer join
        @FileFolders as FF on FF.FileId = Fi.FileId left outer join
        @Folders as Fo on Fo.FolderId = FF.FolderId and Fo.UserId = @UserId
      where Fi.UserId = @UserId )
   select FileId, UserId, FolderId
     from PrivateFiles
   union all
   select FileId, UserId, FolderId
     from SharedFiles;
```

Answer (score 1):

I change your #query2 a bit with `Row_number`

```
;WITH temp AS 
 (
    SELECT
    F.[Id] AS [FileId],
    F.[UserId] AS [FileUserId],
    FO.[Id] AS [FolderId],
    row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY F.Id ORDER BY FO.Id DESC) AS Rn 
   -- if folder id not null (it means that folder belongs to @UserId) 
   --> it will be the first priority -- Rownumber = 1
   FROM
    [File] AS F
   LEFT JOIN
    [FolderFile] FOF ON FOF.[FileId] = F.[Id]
   LEFT JOIN
    [Folder] FO ON FO.[Id] = FOF.[FolderId] AND FO.[UserId] = @UserId 
   WHERE
    F.[UserId] IS NULL
    OR F.[UserId] = @UserId
 )
 SELECT t.FileId, t.FileUserId, t.FolderId FROM temp t
 WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `outer apply()`:

```
declare @UserId varchar(50) = 'user_1';
select 
    FileId = F.Id
  , FileUserId = F.UserId
  , FolderId = x.Id
from [File] as F 
  outer apply (
    select top 1 
      Id = case when fo.UserId = @UserId then fo.Id else null end
    from [FolderFile] fof 
      left join [Folder] fo
        on fo.Id = fof.FolderId
    where fof.FileId = f.id
    order by case when fo.UserId = @UserId then 0 else 1 end
    ) as x
where (f.UserId = @UserId or f.UserId is null);
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/YEAMZ12650

returns:

```
+--------------+------------+--------------+
|    FileId    | FileUserId |   FolderId   |
+--------------+------------+--------------+
| user1_file1  | user_1     | NULL         |
| user1_file2  | user_1     | NULL         |
| shared_file1 | NULL       | user1_folder |
| shared_file2 | NULL       | user1_folder |
| shared_file3 | NULL       | NULL         |
| shared_file4 | NULL       | NULL         |
+--------------+------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

[FolderFile] Table shows that "shared_file1" exists in both user1_folder and user2_folder. Is this correct?

(Sorry, I don't have sufficient point to add a comment.)

Comment: Yes, that is correct, which is what is causing the problem with my current queries. The query should only return results for `user_1`.

Comment: Why you want return  "shared_file1"  for `user_1`? It is still correct if I return only for `user_2`, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
DECLARE @UserId VARCHAR( 50 ) = 'user_1'

SELECT File.Id AS FileId,
       File.UserId AS FileUserId,
       Folder.Id AS FolderId
FROM File
LEFT JOIN FolderFile ON FolderFile.FileId = File.Id
LEFT JOIN Folder ON Folder.Id = FolderFile.FolderId
                AND Folder.UserId = @UserId
WHERE ( File.UserId IS NULL OR
        File.UserId = @UserId )
  AND ( FileUserId IS NOT NULL OR
        FolderId IS NOT NULL )
```

Your second attempted query was close, you just needed to add an exclusionary clause for where both fields are `NULL` / inclusionary clause where at least one field is `NULL`.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

*Further Reading*

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp

Comment: This excludes `shared_file_3`, which is not in a folder.

Answer (score 0):

The extra row is being introduced by the first `LEFT JOIN` to `FolderFile`, not by the `LEFT JOIN` to `Folder`, so adding an extra join condition on the `Folder` table won't eliminate that row.

You can, however, filter the row out in the `WHERE` clause.  Since you want rows for either shared files with no folders e.g. `shared_file3`, or rows for shared files linked to folders belonging to `@UserId`, just add the following filter to query 1.

```
DECLARE @UserId VARCHAR(50) = 'user_1'

SELECT
  F.[Id] AS [FileId],
  F.[UserId] AS [FileUserId],
  FO.[Id] AS [FolderId]
FROM
  [File] AS F
LEFT JOIN
  [FolderFile] FOF ON FOF.[FileId] = F.[Id]
LEFT JOIN
  [Folder] FO ON FO.[Id] = FOF.[FolderId]
WHERE (F.[UserId] IS NULL OR F.[UserId] = @UserId)
  AND (FO.UserId IS NULL OR FO.UserId = @UserId)
```

**Update**

If you only want to include private folders which belong to the user, but still include all shared files, then the following should do the trick.

```
DECLARE @UserId VARCHAR(50) = 'user_1'

SELECT
  F.[Id] AS [FileId],
  F.[UserId] AS [FileUserId],
  FO.[Id] AS [FolderId]
FROM
  [File] AS F
LEFT JOIN
  [FolderFile] FOF ON FOF.[FileId] = F.[Id]
LEFT JOIN
  [Folder] FO ON FO.[Id] = FOF.[FolderId] AND FO.UserId = @UserId
WHERE (F.[UserId] IS NULL OR F.[UserId] = @UserId)
  AND (FO.UserId IS NULL OR FO.UserId = @UserId)
```

Comment: This one looks to be returning the correct results! Let me run through a few more conditions to fully verify it and I will accept if all goes well.

Comment: I found a condition that still causes issues with this query. I have updated the question with `INSERT INTO [File] VALUES ('shared_file4', NULL); INSERT INTO [FolderFile] VALUES ('user2_folder', 'shared_file4');`. This added a new `shared_file4`, which is in `user_2`'s private folder. `shared_file4` should return for `user_1`, but it doesn't.

Comment: @kspearrin that should handle the additional case.

Comment: Update causes a duplicate `shared_file1` still.

Comment: Whoops, well this should be enough to get you started - you can debug more on your own :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
DECLARE @UserId VARCHAR(50) = 'user_1'

SELECT
    F.[Id] AS [FileId],
    F.[UserId] AS [FileUserId],
    FO.[Id] AS [FolderId]
FROM
    [File] AS F
LEFT JOIN
    [FolderFile] FOF ON FOF.[FileId] = F.[Id]
LEFT JOIN
    [Folder] FO ON FO.[Id] = FOF.[FolderId]
WHERE
    FO.[UserId] = @UserId
    OR F.[UserId] = @UserId;
```

Edited: For `shared_file_3`, which has NULL user_id, and not in any folder, If for your design it will appear in all user `shared files` then you should use:

```
DECLARE @UserId VARCHAR(50) = 'user_1'

SELECT
    F.[Id] AS [FileId],
    F.[UserId] AS [FileUserId],
    FO.[Id] AS [FolderId]
FROM
    [File] AS F
LEFT JOIN
    [FolderFile] FOF ON FOF.[FileId] = F.[Id]
LEFT JOIN
    [Folder] FO ON FO.[Id] = FOF.[FolderId]
WHERE
    FO.[UserId] = @UserId
    OR F.[UserId] = @UserId
    OR (FO.[UserId] IS NULL AND F.[UserId] IS NULL);
```

Comment: This excludes `shared_file_3`, which is not in a folder.

Comment: @kspearrin If for your database design, a file that has NULL owner and not in any folders is a shared file of ALL user then you could use my second query in edited answer.

Comment: Your second query includes `shared_file_3` correctly now. However, I found a condition that still causes issues with this query. I have updated the question with `INSERT INTO [File] VALUES ('shared_file4', NULL); INSERT INTO [FolderFile] VALUES ('user2_folder', 'shared_file4');`. This added a new `shared_file_4`, which is in `user_2`'s private folder. `shared_file_4` should return for `user_1`, but it doesn't.